# Examples and definition of multilinear mappings on infinite products

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Can anybody give me examples of multilinear mappings (trivial or non trivial) on an infinite product space $∏_{i\in I} X_i$, where $I$ is an infinite set and $X_i$'s are objects, say vector spaces.

I know the multilinear mappings are defined on finite products ${\times}{^n}_{i=1} X_i$ in the literature, but I'm interested to know how people extended them for infinite products. So any reference for the definition of multilinear mappings on infinite products?

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11767/infinite-tensor-products) question on MO and the paper linked in the answer seems to be what you are looking for. As far as a *non trivial* example of such a map is concerned, I don't know though.

Comment: $∏_{i∈I} Xi$ is a collection of vector spaces, then the map from $∏_{i∈I} Xi$ to a vector space $F$ which sends each $(x_i)$ to $1⨂1⨂1⨂ ...$ is trivial multilinear map on  $∏_{i∈I} Xi$?

Here the vector space $F$ is a space consisting on multilinear mappings on $∏_{i∈I} Xi$ (if they exists).